# Concrete5.7 error 500 before installation page

Tags: php, apache, concrete5

This domain: http://ctc.w3-development.de/ should become a new website. I have changed my hosting provider – and now I cant do a fresh install of C5.7 anymore.

The PHP-Error-Logs throws:

```
error: cannot stat directory: (/kunden/pages/45/90/d0010748/home/htdocs/ctc/index.php)
Premature end of script headers: php56-cgi
```

Check out the PHP-Info-file: http://ctc.w3-development.de/info.php

Should be everything alright? My server does met the requirements. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Humm ... I would expect to see other error rows dropped by php56-cgi on termination.

Comment: That´s the only... :(

Comment: sounds like either that directory doesn't exist or it doesn't have executable permissions.

Comment: All my folders and files was 755 / 644. Have changed that to 755 already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my server configuration: It works after deactivating allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include.